# Streaming data into delta lake, reading filtered results

Tags: java, apache-spark, kotlin, delta-lake

My goal is to continuously put incoming parquet files into delta-lake, make queries, and get the results into a Rest API.
All files are in s3 buckets.

```
//listen for changes
val df = spark.readStream().parquet("s3a://myBucket/folder")

//write changes to delta lake
df.writeStream()
    .format("delta")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "s3a://myBucket-processed/checkpoint")
    .start("s3a://myBucket-processed/")
    .awaitTermination() //this call lives in another thread (because it's blocking)

//this is a bad example
val query = df.select(convertedColumnNames) 
query.show()

//another bad example:
spark.readStream().format("delta").load("s3a://myBucket-processed/").select(convertedColumnNames).show()

//org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

How can I get the filtered data out from delta lake?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [foreachBatch](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch)?

It brings all batch like features to streaming and you can also somewhat control number of files you are writing into delta lake.

Comment: use "git fetch" to get all remote branch to your local.